# Why does Gutenberg adds 4 <br> around blocks? And how to change this?

Tags: block-editor

I recently wondered why Gutenberg renders 4 `<br>` tags around the blocks. 
Maybe 2 before and 2 after. It makes it difficult to style.

How can I remove them?

[image: <br> around gutenberg blocks]

Comment: That's not default behavior unless you entered line breaks in the text.

Comment: Thank you. Thats interesting. I checked the content of the blocks and there are no line breaks in the editor. Any idea what else in the theme or plugins could be responsible for this behaviour?

Comment: Really difficult to debug from afar. What plugins you use, what theme you use, what custom code you built? We'd need to know all that to help you any further.

Comment: How would you debug problems like this if it was your project? Is there a way to get a list of all code/hooks/filters that are modifying the final output?

Comment: I'd try to track it down systematically. Vanilla WordPress. Switching on plugins on by one. Switching theme. Disabling JavaScript. Xdebug.